# Cannot pass datetime from value field within the jquery

Tags: javascript, mysql, datetime

I have this code which adds textbox after every half an hour 
this is the screenshot of that [image]

The thing I have marked is the the `yo` variable.
This is part of the code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    document.getElementById('time').value = yo;
    var data=$('#data').val();
    var counter = 1;
    var d=new Date();
    var i;
    var newdate= new Array();
    newdate=$('#newdate').val();
    newdate= newdate.replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
    var newdate1=newdate.split(",");
    var a=newdate1[0];
    var b=newdate1[1];
    var c=newdate1[2];
    var dateString=$('#strtime').val();
    var dateString2=$('#endtime').val();
    var dateString1=$('#date').val();
    var d1 = new Date(dateString1+" "+dateString);
    var d5= new Date(dateString1+" "+dateString2);
    var yo=d1;
    var d3=new Date(dateString1+" "+a);
    var d4=new Date(dateString1+" "+b);

    function msToTime(Milliseconds)
    {
        var d = new Date(Milliseconds);
        return [d.getHours(), d.getMinutes(), d.getSeconds()].join(':');
    }
    setInterval(function() {
        var xtime=null;
        if(yo.getTime() <= d.getTime() && yo.getTime() <= d5.getTime()){
            if( (d1.getTime() == d3.getTime()) || (d1.getTime() == d4.getTime())){
                var freq=$('#freq').val();
                freq=parseInt(freq);
                var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);
                newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<div><label style="float:left;">'+yo+'</label></div><textarea name="textbox' + counter + '" id="textbox' + counter + '" ></textarea><input type="hidden" id="time" name="time" value='+yo+'/>');
                newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");
                yo.setMinutes(yo.getMinutes() + freq);
            }
            counter++;
        }
    },1000);
});
</script>
```

The yo value appears in the label as you can see in the screenshot.But when I type something in the textbox of 14:30 and send it to the database,for some reason only fri gets passed and I get a mysql error

```
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: 'Fri' for column 'time' at row 1
```

The column in mysql is datetime.

I also tried with time column. and the code I had used was the same except for this line

```
newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<div><label style="float:left;">'+yo+'</label></div><textarea  readonly="readonly" name="textbox' + counter + '" id="textbox' + counter + '" value="'+msToTime(yo.getTime())+'0" />');
```

In the value of the hidden field I used to take the milliseconds and convert to only time and pass to the database.The time used to pass but not 14:30 but instead 11:30.The first time.

Please provide me suggestions on either of them.

**UPDATE**

```
<%
java.util.Date now = new java.util.Date();
String DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);
String date = sdf.format(now) ;
String time=request.getParameter("time");
String data0=request.getParameter("textbox1");
String data1=request.getParameter("textbox2");
String data2=request.getParameter("textbox3");
String data3=request.getParameter("textbox4");
String data4=request.getParameter("textbox5");
String data5=request.getParameter("textbox6");
String data6=request.getParameter("textbox7");
String data7=request.getParameter("textbox8");
String data8=request.getParameter("textbox9");
String data9=request.getParameter("textbox10");
String data10=request.getParameter("textbox11");
String data11=request.getParameter("textbox12");
String data12=request.getParameter("textbox13");
String data13=request.getParameter("textbox14");
String user = session.getAttribute("par1").toString();
Connection con=null;
String message="";
try{
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gla", "root", "root");
Statement st=con.createStatement();
String sql = "INSERT INTO user_data (date,user,data0,data1,data2,data3,data4,data5,data6,data7,data8,data9,data10,data11,data12,data13,time) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement(sql);
statement.setString(1, date);
statement.setString(2, user);
statement.setString(3, data0);
statement.setString(4, data1);
statement.setString(5, data2);
statement.setString(6, data3);
statement.setString(7, data4);
statement.setString(8, data5);
statement.setString(9, data6);
statement.setString(10, data7);
statement.setString(11, data8);
statement.setString(12, data9);
statement.setString(13, data10);
statement.setString(14, data11);
statement.setString(15, data12);
statement.setString(16, data13);
statement.setString(17, time);
int row = statement.executeUpdate();
if (row > 0) {
    message="Edit";
}

} 
catch (SQLException ex) 
{
message = "ERROR: " + ex.getMessage();
ex.printStackTrace();
} 
finally {
if (con != null) {
    // closes the database connection
    try {
        con.close();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
%>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put quotes around the value in the hidden input. Otherwise, the attribute ends at the space after `Fri`.

```
newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<div><label style="float:left;">'+yo+'</label></div><textarea name="textbox' + counter + '" id="textbox' + counter + '" ></textarea><input type="hidden" name="time" value="'+yo+'"/>');
```

However, this probably won't work, either. I don't think MySQL understands dates in the format you're entering them. It wants them in the format `2013-12-27`, not `Fri Dec 27 2013`. You need to convert the dates to this format, either in Javascript or in the server program, or in your SQL with the `STR_TO_DATE` function.

The reason you're getting the wrong time is because your form has multiple `<input type="hidden" name="time" value="XXX"/>` elements. When you submit the form, only the first one gets used.

Instead of appending a new `time` input each time, you should update the existing one. Add `id="time"` to the original hidden input, and then do:

```
$("#time").value(yo);
```

in your `setInterval` function. It should be:

```
setInterval(function() {
    var xtime=null;
    if(yo.getTime() <= d.getTime() && yo.getTime() <= d5.getTime()){
        if( (d1.getTime() == d3.getTime()) || (d1.getTime() == d4.getTime())){
            var freq=$('#freq').val();
            freq=parseInt(freq);
            var newTextBoxDiv = $("<div>", { "id": 'TextBoxDiv' + counter });
            newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<div><label style="float:left;">'+yo+'</label></div><textarea name="textbox' + counter + '" id="textbox' + counter + '" ></textarea>');
            newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");
            $("#time").val(yo);
            yo.setMinutes(yo.getMinutes() + freq);
        }
        counter++;
    }
},1000);
```

Comment: Is there a way to convert and use it in mysql then?thats also another reason I wanted to do it the second way as I mentioned in my question above

Comment: In both ways the previous date is passing,I dont know how to resolve that...Your way works no doubt.I just tried it out

Comment: You haven't posted the code that submits to the server, how can I tell what it's doing wrong?

Comment: 11:30 is the first time, not the previous time. That's probably a clue to what's going wrong.

Comment: No actually  the thing is there are 6 users.1st user comes at 11:30,2nd user at 12:00 and so.Then at 14:30 the user1 comes back and types.But whatever he types at 14:30 gets passed as 11:30.Similarly with user2,whatever he types at 15:00 gets passed as 12:00.

Comment: Is it always 3 hours earlier?

Comment: depends here the frequency of occurence is 30mins.it could be 15mins or even 45mins depending what the admin sets.I have updated

Comment: That's not what I asked. 14:30 is 3 hours off from 11:30, and 15:00 is 3 hours off from 12:00. Does it always pass a time 3 hours different from when the user typed?

Comment: yes,it passes the 1st instance of the user when he comes.so in this case 11.30.The counter variable works fines,dont know y this doesnt work.

Comment: I have tried the same  code I have updated above but nothings appears,once I remove this line `document.getElementById('time').value = yo;`the code works,but gives the same previous results.Also what do you mean by original hidden field

Comment: When the page is first displayed, you should create a field `<input type="hidden" id="time" name="time" value="..."/>` with the initial time. Then that code will update it every time period, so it will always contain the latest time. You should not add a new one each time.

Comment: so u mean this hidden field,should I add in the body of html page?

Comment: Yes, you could do that.

Comment: but then I wont be able to pass the `yo variable` there

Comment: Yes, because the interval function will update it with the code I suggested.

Comment: That's the other problem I mentioned in my answer. You need to format the date so that MySQL understands it.

Comment: oh yeah.remembered thnx for all the help.I am using the second method anyways,which I am passing only time..thnx again

Comment: it passes a null value.I did whatever U said.it passes a null value

Comment: not exactly.But this was kind of another question na.That was a seperate part.ny idea y the null value is passing?I have kept hidden field in the form in the body of the html

Comment: Just realised now it passes only the 2nd time,even when I send from the first textbox..what should I do?